# Convert a string (without separators) into IPV6 address representation

Tags: python, ip-address, ipv6

I'm trying to get the local IPV6 address by reading `/proc/net/if_inet6`. But the address there is without any colons like: `000000000000000000000abc00070def`.

So I'm adding colons (:) at multiple places like this:

```
str6 = "000000000000000000000abc00070def"
i = 4
addr = str6[:i]
while i < len(str6):
    addr += ":" + str6[i:i+4]
    i += 4
print addr     # output: 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0abc:0007:0def
```

For a normal string this is working fine.

But since the string is a IPV6 address, so wondering is there a better way to do it? (Tried with ipaddress module but I don't think it supports without colons.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ipaddress.IPv6Address`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv6Address) can also construct an IPv6 address from a *"valid"* integer:

```
import ipaddress

ipv6_addr = ipaddress.ip_address(int('000000000000000000000abc00070def', 16))
print(ipv6_addr)
```

prints:

```
::abc:7:def
```

The long form of the address representation (*exploded*):

```
print(ipv6_addr.exploded)
```

prints:

```
0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0abc:0007:0def
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. `ipv6_addr.explode` will give the long form. There is no need to use `IPv6Address`.